# Replace NSURLConnection+delegate with NSURLSession+delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask, nsurlsessiontask

First of all there a lot of similar questions but they are all about creating of `NSURLSessionDataTask` with completion handler. In my case I have `NSURLConnection` with a lot of delegate methods and I need to replace it with `NSURLSession`.

[According to this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html) I need delegate method `URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:` but I can't understand how to use it because all the examples are about creating a task with a completion handler (just success or failure) with no delegate usage at all.

Comment: Did you tried by setting the delegate of a `NSURLSession` object, and implementing that delegate method if it's called? I may guess that the delegate method will be called before the completion handlers (success/error) of the `NSURLSession` object.

Comment: I mean I don't how to set `NSURLSession` method. I can't just write `[NSURLSession sharedSession].delegate = self`. Finally the method I mentioned requires `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`, not `NSURLSessionDelegate` from `NSURLSession`.

Comment: You can use `sessionWithConfiguration: delegate: delegateQueue:`. As the doc said with `[NSURLSession sharedSession]`: "As a result, you don’t provide a delegate or a configuration object.".